# laravel 8 ajax y csrf mismatch

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax

Estoy realizando el llenado de un campo select a traves de ajax y jquery pero el momento de enviar los datos al controlador me da el Error de

> "message": "CSRF token mismatch.",

tengo el head en una layout aparte donde cargo todas las clases de css y los script, adicionalmente este layout lo elabore con la plantilla adminLTE3, no se si por esta este generando el problema en el CSRF

```
<head>
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>@yield('title')</title>

  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  {{-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('fontawesome/css/all.css')}}"> --}}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css')}}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('fontawesome6/css/fontawesome.min.css')}}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('fontawesome6/css/brands.min.css')}}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('fontawesome6/css/solid.min.css')}}">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Tempusdominus Bootstrap 4 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css')}}">
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css')}}">
  <!-- JQVMap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css')}}">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
  <!-- overlayScrollbars -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css')}}">
  <!-- Daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css')}}">
  <!-- summernote -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.css')}}">
 <!-- DataTables -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css')}}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css')}}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('plugins/datatables-buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css')}}">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('dist/css/adminlte.min.css')}}">
</head>
```

esta es la funcion de jquery que utilizo para hacer el llenado del segundo campo select

```
function llenarModelo(){
    var marca = $('#marca').val()
    var token = $('#token').val()
    $.ajax({
        url : '/llenarModelo',
        type : 'post',
        data :{
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            id_marca : marca
        },
        success:function(modelo){
            console.log(modelo)
        }
    })
}
```

y en mi controlador solo espero recibir el id_marca para proceder a hacer el query y devolver los valores segun el codigo del id

```
public function llenarModelo(){
        $marca = $_POST['marca'];
        dd($marca);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo he usado estas 2 opciones para extraer el token

Esta es la que viene directo del meta.

```
 headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
```

y este es cuando incluyes el token en el form (@csrf)

```
 headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
```

prueba a ver si alguna te es de ayuda

Comment: listo, funciono la segunda linea, muchas Gracias